# .Net Client - Java server Connection problem using tls1.2

Tags: java, .net, ssl, tls1.2

I have a problem connecting from my .Net client to Java server, both were changed from TLS1 to TLS1.2.
Both client and server in the same machine, Windows10 64bits.

.Net client created under .Net Framework 4.5, using HttpWebRequest.
Previous the request call I set

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

.Net Error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

---

Java using jdk1.8.0_25
Java Error log:

```
P-86, received EOFException: error
P-86, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host                 
closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
P-86, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
P-86, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
P-86, called closeSocket()
P-86, called close()
P-86, called closeInternal(true)
```

I have changed to different ciphers with no success. Any suggestion to follow ?
thanks

Comment: You'd better move them to different machines, and then use a tool like Wireshark to capture TLS handshakes. That should give you more data to check, than the limited log entries right now from Java side. .NET Network Tracing might help as well, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing but it is difficult to analyze compared to Wireshark capture.

Comment: As an additional info I tried using TLSv1.1 and it works.

Comment: TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2 are different things (different ciphers for instance), so focus on the 1.2 issue please.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the certificate.I was using a very old one, I changed it and It works. I'm not clear why, I'm investigating.

Thanks to all.